# Why avoid the classic peaks of the balkans trail?

Tags: hiking, european-long-distance-paths

From https://bnadventure.com/self-guided-tour-in-the-peaks-of-the-balkans/:

> The trail avoids the classic peaks of the Balkans trail as the situation in the mountains has changed since the trail was established. This itinerary takes that into account and provides the best views and best experience.

That sounds like there may be a problem with the classic peaks of the Balkans trail.  How has the situation changed?  Has the trail been abandoned in parts?  Is it the opposite problem and is it too busy?  Has it been blocked or made less interesting by new developments?  Or is there not actually much of a problem at all?

Comment: "the situation in the mountains has changed since the trail was established". I suspect this suggests political tensions, or claims of ownership/border disputes. From your source: "This itinerary takes a shortcut from Albania to Montenegro, cutting out Kosovo and Doberdol." Kosovo has had a contentious separation from Serbia relatively recently. But this is just supposition, so not an answer. Likewise, I'd imagine tours, especially self-guided ones, in the Himalayas avoid the disputed section of the China-India border, for example.

Comment: The Kosovo separation from Serbia was 14 years ago (2008), whereas the trail is quite recent, probably newer than that.  So although it could be that it's due to political developments, those would be developments much more recently than Kosovo independence.

Comment: All I can say is that the Bulgarian part of the E4 trail passes through all major peaks. Some people use motorized vehicles and they avoid some peaks as it's impossible to lift heavy machinery there.

Comment: @Vorac They use motorised vehicles on the hiking trail?

Comment: @gerrit yes, it's a corrupt country with little regard for the law, the only thing that keeps the nature rather intact is the sparsity of the population. At least those fat "tourists" can't get [here](https://patekite.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/kupena-spuskane.jpeg).